Maximze Sharpe ratio from matlab to python
I know there matlab library funtion for
Optimzing Sharpe ratio
estimateMaxSharpeRatio, it mentioned it use direct method
How can i do the same thing in python
Is there any python libraries
Or need customized function? No idea. Scipy?

Try scipy.optimize or cvxopt libraries.

Your answer would be more helpful if you explained in some detail how these libraries might be used given the question.

The question asks about the 'direct method' for maximizing Sharpe; this refers to the method described in the book by Cornuejols and Tutuncu, section 8.2 This method is based on solving a Quadratic Program formulation shown on page 157. So a library that can solve quadratic programs would be helpful in writing the code that the question is concerned with. (Of course it would be even better if one could find code already written).
